# laravel 8 database queue withoutoverlapping

Tags: database, queue, laravel-8, race-condition

i have 3 tables

table A - store wallet balance

table B - store transaction

table C - store final amount for each transaction

i develop a job function to process amount in table B

step 1: get balance from table A by member_id

step 2: get transaction from table B by member_id to decide deduct or add on balance

step 3: udpate table A to latest balance, store starting and ending balance in table C

i'm using withoutoverlapping

```
public function middleware(){
    return [new WithoutOverLapping($this->_member_id)];
}
```

i'm running 3 job at the same time, for testing purpose, my test data (around 6k record) on table B is all same member_id, the result that i expect is data in table C (starting ending balance) all follow sequence, but after running, starting amount in some of the record (a few) are same (means wrong, starting amount should same with ending amount of previous row), i'm not sure where goes wrong, any advice how to make them all precise?

Comment: Presumably table C is related to table B via a transaction ID, and not a member ID? As that may be why the WithoutOverlapping isn't working - with no member ID, it doesn't care about timing for step 3. I think it's WithoutOverlapping, by the way, rather than WithoutOverLapping (but not sure if that would make a difference?)

Comment: Hi, table C is actually treat as audit/checking/log table, the reason i use member_id as unique is because when actual data come, 3 job can do the calculation at the same time as long as the wallet belongs to different member_id. Reason i use same member_id is hope that 3 jobs will process 1 by 1 till the end, and all result is in sequence (kind of stress test)

Comment: Is there scope to merge it all into one job rather than three? As all the items being entered are related to one specific transaction, that would avoid the issue, no? You could then have that master job WithoutOverlapping.